# Javascript - Disable Select Option Elements Based on Selected Option

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple form with two select elements. Each of the two select elements have some options and in those options some values. The first select with the id "average" has five options. The second one with the id "amount" has three options. What I would like is, if the user select from the "average" the option that has the value of "D", to disable all the options from the "amount" and only be available for selection the option with the value of "30". I have tried something but it is not working. Hopefully someone can help with this issue.

Thanks

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">  
      <select id="average">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D" id="special">D</option>
          <option value="E">E</option>
      </select>

      <select id="amount">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30" id="onlyAmount">30</option>
      </select>  
  </form>
```

JavaScript

```
var myAverage = document.querySelector("#average");
var mySpecial = document.querySelector("#special");
var myAmount = document.querySelector("#amount");
var onlyAmount = document.querySelector("#onlyAmount");


if( mySpecial.value.selected ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < myAmount.children.length; i++ ) {
        myAmount[i].disabled = true;
    }
    onlyAmount.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is fine, except you're doing it too early. What you want is to run your code *when the user interacts with the first dropdown*. Have you heard of [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) before?

Comment: Thank you for ur answer @Touffy , how would u make it work?

Comment: Sorry, that's not how it's supposed to work ;) you read the documentation, give it a try, and *if you still need help* then you post a better question here and we gladly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="#" method="post">  
      <select id="average">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D" id="special">D</option>
          <option value="E">E</option>
      </select>

      <select id="amount">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30" id="onlyAmount">30</option>
      </select>  
  </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){
  var myAverage = document.querySelector("#average");
  var mySpecial = document.querySelector("#special");
  var myAmount = document.querySelector("#amount");
  var onlyAmount = document.querySelector("#onlyAmount");


  myAverage.addEventListener('change', function(){
   debugger;
   if( myAverage.value === 'D' ) {
    myAmount.value = "";
       for ( var i = 0; i < myAmount.children.length; i++ ) {
           myAmount[i].disabled = true;
       }
       onlyAmount.disabled = false;
   }else{
    for ( var i = 0; i < myAmount.children.length; i++ ) {
           myAmount[i].disabled = false;
       }
   }   
  })
 })();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working Plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/gXW4azAqKPWwsrUoNwak?p=preview

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener` to check for user selecting a new item from the dropdown. You can then call a function to apply the logic per your original code.

```js
var myAverage = document.querySelector("#average");
var mySpecial = document.querySelector("#special");
var myAmount = document.querySelector("#amount");
var onlyAmount = document.querySelector("#onlyAmount");

myAverage.addEventListener('change', analyseUserSelection);

function analyseUserSelection(e) {
  if (mySpecial.selected) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myAmount.children.length; i++) {
      myAmount[i].disabled = true;
    }
    onlyAmount.disabled = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <select id="average">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D" id="special">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>

  <select id="amount">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30" id="onlyAmount">30</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin Mackenzie for ur answer ur code is working. Moreover, when I select the option with the value of "D" the option from the "amount" becomes disabled as expected. However, when I change it back to any of the other options of the "average" the options in "amount" are also disabled. What I would like is, only if the option with the value of "D" is selected to disable the options in the "amount" and keep the option with the value of "30".

Comment: OK - well know you know you to hook the event you can implement extra logic for the other things you are mentioning.... it's good etiquette to try and not add extra requirements after someone answered your question :)